# MacOSX Catalina - Memory leak and physical memory exhuastion

Tags: c, operating-system, computer-science

I have created a program in C that allocates 1GB worth of memory per iteration, exhausting the virtual memory by sending a kill switch to the process after 120gb of memory has been used.

**The code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void leakme() {
    int onegb = 1024 * 1024 * 1024; //One Gigabyte
    int *mem = malloc(onegb);
    memset(mem,0,onegb);
    //Don't free memory
    return;
}

int main(){
    int z;
    printf("Staring allocating memory in 1GB chucks\n");
    printf("How much memory would you like to allocate?\n");
    fflush(stdout); //Flush buffer
    scanf("%d", &z);
    for(int i=1; i<=z;i++){
        leakme();
        printf("Gigabytes of memory allocated: %d \n", i);
        printf("----------------------------\n");
        fflush(stdout); //Flush buffer
        //sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Whilst watching this through the activity monitor, I have noticed that the physical memory never exceeds 4GB. Is this due to the OS limiting the amount of physical memory a process can use?
I understand that this program exhausts virtual memory, but is there a way to exhaust the physical memory also?

Edit: The system has 16GB of physical memory.

Comment: What happens if you check whether malloc failed? Does malloc keep succeeding or are you only successful the first couple of times?

Comment: @4386427 Hi, It has 16GB

Comment: @wxz it succeeds indefinitely until the OS kills it.

Comment: Could it be "compressed memory" ? After all 1GB region with all zeros can be compressed to nearly nothing

Comment: And how about Swap? Maybe you should post a picture of the Activity monitor

Comment: Also - I wouldn't leak the memory. A clever compiler/a clever system could detect that and do "funny stuff". Instead let the function return the memory pointers and save all pointer in an array

Comment: OT: `fflush(stdout);` why?